# incompatibility with btoa and IE

Tags: javascript

It seems that internet explorer with version smaller than 9 is not compatible with btoa.
Then how can you export in excel?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;ase64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
  return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
  }
  if (window.btoa) {
    msg.dataEncoded = window.btoa(msg.data);
} else { //for <= IE9
    msg.dataEncoded = jQuery.base64.encode(msg.data);
}
})()

</script>
```

Comment: Do you want to export in client side only? If you are using node server then you can use json2xls module which works great to export JSON object to excel in simple steps.
let fs = require("fs");
let json2xls = require('json2xls');
let path = require("path");
let xls = json2xls(jsonData); let xlsFileName = path.resolve(folder, filename);fs.writeFileSync(xlsFileName, xls, 'binary');

Comment: Been awhile since I had to think about IE8, but aren't data urls not supported unless they are in CSS files? Do you really have IE8 users still?